# Issues of scattering pandas dataframe with 'mpi4py' and and do mathematical computation for BIG array?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, mpi, scipy-optimize, mpi4py

I've a big matrix/array and try to send all possible pair of columns to the various processor in the cluster computer. Here, I've created a random data frame to use mpi4py. To do this, I've sent/scatter the name of the column pair to various process but can not send the data of the respective columns. Can anyone suggest me how to scatter the dataframes efficiently and gather all the process result to the master process[@rank==0]? Any help will be appreciated.

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import itertools
import glob
import time
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
name= MPI.Get_processor_name()
print('The no. of nprocs is :', size)
print('The name of the processor is :', name)


# Function create Real part of Coherence
def myFunc(X,Y):
..................
..................
    return Real_coh

# Create a random dataframe
df = DataFrame(data=np.random.random((500, 34)), columns=[f'Col_{i:03}' for i in range(1, 35)])
real_coherence = {} # Create a dictionary
columns = df.columns.to_list() # list


if rank==0:
#All possible Names of column pairs
    all_col = list(itertools.combinations(columns, 2))
# dividing all possible column pairs into chunks
    chunks = [[] for _ in range(size)]
    for i, chunk in enumerate(all_col):
        chunks[i % size].append(chunk)
else:
    data = None
    chunks = None
data = comm.scatter(chunks, root=0)
print('Process {} has data:'.format(rank), data)

# Now I want to allocate the dataframe to the column names

col_a,col_b = chunks #[<---I guess the problem is here]

aa = df.loc[:, col_a] # panda core series
bb = df.loc[:, col_b]
dset_x = aa.to_numpy()  # panda core series to Numpy array
dset_y = bb.to_numpy()
real_coh[col_a + '_&_' + col_b] = myFunc(dset_x, dset_y)    
result = DataFrame.from_dict(real_coh, orient='index')
result_sorted = result.sort_index()
result = result_sorted.to_numpy()

# Send the results back to the master processes
final_result = comm.gather(result, root=0)

    
if (rank==0):
    print("The resulting vector is: " "   ", final_result, "computed in parallel")
    print(result_sorted.to_numpy().shape)
    print('Time required:', time.time()-start_time)
```

I've supplied the piece of code which I'm trying:

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import itertools
import glob
import time
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
name= MPI.Get_processor_name()

data=np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)
df = DataFrame(data=data, columns=[f'Col_{i:02}' for i in range(1, 5)])
correlations = {} # as a dictionary
columns = df.columns.to_list() # list

if rank == 0:
    for c in combinations(df, 2):
        comm.Send(c, dest=1, tag=13)
        x, y = c
        xdat = df[x].to_list()
        ydat = df[y].to_list()
        real_coh[col_a + '_&_' + col_b] = myFunc(dset_x, dset_y)    
        result = DataFrame.from_dict(real_coh, orient='index')
        result_sorted = result.sort_index()
        result = result_sorted.to_numpy()
         ..........................
```

Is this the right approach? Sorry for my poor explanation. Could anybody help me on the right approach?
I've used `mpirun -np 4 python3 file_name.py` in the command line.

Comment: You are creating `chunks` as a python array of arrays. I kinda doubt that you can scatter that. It will definitely be inefficient. Create it as a `numpy` two-dimensional array. (Using `append` is totally bogus: you know how many columns there are; just write the data directly into that column.) Python uses different mechanism for sending/scattering native objects than for numpy objects, and it's demonstrably much slower.

Comment: Thanks, Victor Eijkhout. I tried to send the name of the columns to the worker process and then the corresponding data of the columns. To do this with chunks, I've sent the names of the columns but I don't know how can I send the data/dataframe of the column pair to the worker process. With numpy, if I create all possible pair of columns of the 2D array, is this create memory flooding. 2D array size is ~14GB. Any idea will be greatly acknowledged.

Comment: The whole point of MPI is that you keep your data distributed. So you should never create it all in one place and then scatter: let each process create its own part.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you please give me some links or hints regarding this? I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Any MPI tutorial should teach you this. It's the basic idea behind MPI. You are too much thinking that there is some central/manager process. There is not. You need to create and process everything distributed. https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-functional.html#Distributedcomputinganddistributeddata